# Quartz Scheduing: Using DailyCalendar

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to schedule a quartz job according to the following plan:

Job runs daily and should only be executed between 9:30am and 6:00pm. I am trying to achieve this via DailyCalendar. Here what my DailyCalendar looks like:

```
DailyCalendar dCal = new DailyCalendar(startTimeString, endTimeString);
dCal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
dCal.setInvertTimeRange(true);
```

where start and end time strings are of the format HH:MM

Next, I try to schedule this job:

```
Scheduler myscheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
SimpleTrigger trigger = new SimpleTrigger();
myscheduler.addCalendar("todcal", cal, true, true);
trigger.setName("TRIGGER " + alertName);
trigger.setJobName(alertName);
trigger.setJobGroup(alertName);
trigger.setCalendarName("todcal");
logger.info("Adding TOD job");
myscheduler.scheduleJob(trigger);    // line causing exception
myscheduler.start();
```

As soon as scheduleJob is called I see the following Exception:

```
Based on configured schedule, the given trigger will never fire.
```

The configuration seems fine to me but I cant find any sample code for using DailyCalendar so I could be wrong here. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to be setting a repeat count or repeat interval on your trigger.  So it will only fire once at the current moment (because you did not set a future start time), which probably happens to be during the calendar's exclusion time - which is why it would be calculated that it will never fire.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, after providing the repeat count and interval I was able to schedule the jobs

Answer (score 0):

> Job runs daily and should only be
>   executed between 9:30am and 6:00pm.

How often should the job be executed within that timeframe? Once? Once an hour? Every 10 seconds?

You need to define the repeat interval for your trigger. Look at `setRepeatInterval(long repeatInterval)` method of `SimpleTrigger`. It defines in milliseconds the interval with which the trigger will repeat.

Comment: Thanks, after providing the repeat count and interval I was able to schedule the jobs